# PHP compiler doesn't find any libraries

Tags: php, windows, compiler-construction, sdk

I'm following [this tutorial](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) to compile PHP on windows.

I'm now at the last steps, but for some reason I get a whole lot of errors like

> WARNING: zlib support can't be enabled, zlib is missing

Despite the fact that `zlib` is definitely present under `ext/` in the PHP sources I use.

Where do I need to put that folder so the compiler can "see" it?

Comment: Besides asking why you need to compile a Windows version of PHP anyway, when the binaries are available for download; `Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]`

Comment: @MarkBaker Long story. Believe me, I have ruled every other possibility out. I knew it would be a pain, but in the constellation I don't see any other possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zlib` extension source code might indeed be in the ext/ folder, but are you sure that your compiler knows where the dependancies (such as the zlib library) are?

Have you seen http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs ?

There is a download provided by PHP at http://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/ where you can get binary versions of all the PHP dependancies for Windows (which will save *a lot* of time).

What version of VC++ do you have installed?